# Keyerror en Django

Tags: base-de-datos, django

Me marca un error en un lugar que ni siquiera estaba editando. Lo unico q hice q podria afectar a toda la pagina, es q borré la base de datos y la volví a construir para agregar algunos cambios, ahora me da Keyerror cada vez q intento entrar.

Esto es lo q dice el cmd:

KeyError: 'carro'
[14/May/2021 01:57:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 95353

El error está en esta linea:

```
for key, value in request.session["carro"].items():
```

Lo raro es que antes funcionaba bien. Q creen q pudo haber fallado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que el key 'carro' no existe en tu sesión, antes de ese for tienes que validar que 'carro' exista, puedes hacerlo así:

```
if 'carro' in request.session:
    for key, value in request.session["carro"].items(): 
        pass # hacer algo
```

Comment: Gracias te amo <3